# How to add 2 arrays of custom object into one unique array based on property Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, unique

Let's say I have a custom class which looks like this

```
class Person: NSObject {

    let name: String
    let id: Int


    init(name: String, id: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

and I have 2 arrays of objects

```
        let p1 = Person(name: "as", id: 1)
        let p2 = Person(name: "sa", id: 100)
        let p3 = Person(name: "fa", id: 8)
        let p4 = Person(name: "wq", id: 5)
        let p5 = Person(name: "wqq", id: 123)

        let p10 = Person(name: "sad", id: 8)
        let p11 = Person(name: "cxz", id: 12)
        let p12 = Person(name: "vcx", id: 11)
        let p13 = Person(name: "xc", id: 1)

        let arrPerson = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]
        let arrPersonB = [p10, p11, p12, p13]
```

I need to add this two arrays into one unique array of objects based on their id. So the unique array should contain `[p2, p4, p5, p11, p12]`.

Comment: You must have tried *something* – don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that it does not look like a "write the code for me" question.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to count the occurrences of every `id` and only take a `Person` if the count is 1.

```
let allPersons = arrPerson + arrPersonB
var occurences: [Int: Int] = [:]
allPersons.forEach { occurences[$0.id, default: 0] += 1}
//[12: 1, 11: 1, 123: 1, 100: 1, 5: 1, 1: 2, 8: 2]
let uniquePersons = occurences
    .filter({ $0.value == 1 })
    .map({ id -> Person in
        allPersons.first(where: { $0.id == id.key })!
    })
print(uniquePersons.map { $0.id }) //[12, 100, 123, 5, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ways to do this. Here's one using `NSCountedSet`:

```
let idSet = NSCountedSet(array: (arrPersonA + arrPersonB).map { $0.id })
let arr = (arrPersonA + arrPersonB).filter { idSet.count(for: $0.id) == 1 }
```

- `NSCountedSet` contains a list of all `id`s and their number of occurances
- The second line filter for items that that only occur once in the set

Answer (score 0):

This is a flexible way to make a sequence unique with a custom matching function.

Keep in mind that you would need to adjust this in order to gain control which one of your objects you prefer to keep.

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Hashable {

    func unique(matching: (Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> [Iterator.Element] {

        var uniqueArray: [Iterator.Element] = []
        forEach { element in
            let isUnique = uniqueArray.reduce(true, { (result, item) -> Bool in
                return result && matching(element, item)
            })
            if isUnique {
                uniqueArray.append(element)
            }
        }
        return uniqueArray
    }
}
```

In your case the call would be

```
let uniqueArray = (arrPerson+arrPersonB).unique { $0.id != $1.id }
print(uniqueArray.map { $0.id }) // [1, 100, 8, 5, 123, 12, 11]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use .filter to select only the elements you want based on whatever condition you'd like

For example :

```
let ids = [4, 5, 6, 7] // list of the IDs you want to select

var finalPersons = arrPerson // we copy the first array
finalPersons.append(contentsOf: arrPersonB) // we append the content of the second
finalPersons = finalPersons.filter{ ids.contains($0.id) } // finally we filter to retain only those Persons who corresponds
```